# RSpec - "POST" action gets called only once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I have a problem with calling 'POST' method only once in my test suits.

```
let(:foo) {post :foo_controller arguments}


it 'FIRST: should validate post response first field' do
  expect(foo[:first_field]).to match('something')
end

it 'SECOND: should validate post response second field' do
    expect(foo[:second_field]).to match('something else')
end
```

Now foo's "POST" action is called twice.
I would like to make it that FIRST requests 'POST' and gets a request value, but SECOND only gets a value, which is persisted, without calling this 'POST'.

Is there an elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: Put both `expects` in one `it` block?

Comment: It not so much elegant, but you have right.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a before(:all) block, not sure what post actually returns though.

```
before(:all) do
  @my_response = post :foo_controller arguments
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work when is about calling controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I us a small helper to fix this issue for me.

This is the helper module:

```
module ControllerSpecHelpers

  # example: 
  #
  # describe 'my request' do
  #   examine_response {get '/foo/bar'}
  #   it {should be_ok}
  # end
  #
  #
  def examine_response &block
    before(:all) do 
      self.instance_exec &block
    end
    subject {last_response}
  end

end
```

I configure Rspec to use it in my spec helper:

```
RSpec.configure do |conf|
  # snip ...
  conf.extend ControllerSpecHelpers
end
```

Then when I need to execute the call only once, and test multiple properties, I use it like this:

```
describe "when signing up" do
  examine_response do
    post "/signup", {email: 'signup@test.com', password: 'password'}
  end

  it {should be_ok}
  it "body says welcome" do
    expect(subject.body).to include 'welcome'
  end
end
```

Here's more detail on how extending Rspec works: 
http://timnew.github.io/blog/2012/08/05/extend-rspec-dsl/

Comment: I will try this solution in near future.